# different behaviors observed for a @RequestParam in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to work with `@RequestParam` on a controller to handle different permutations of sorting.  However, it seems to be handling my requests in unexpected ways.  Here's my para in the controller method:

```
@RequestParam(defaultValue = "id,desc") String[] sort
```

Here are some different scenarios and what's parsed into the variable

| query string | parsed value |
| --- | --- |
| ?sort= | ["id","desc"] (default) |
| ?sort=firstName | ["firstName"] |
| ?sort=lastName,desc | ["lastName","desc"] |
| ?sort=lastName&sort=entryDate,desc | ["lastName","entryDate,desc"] |
| ?sort=lastName,desc&sort=entryDate,asc | ["lastName,desc","entryDate,asc"] |

As you can see, it changes how the strings are parsed if more than one query param is specified. It makes it difficult to always treat the variable the same way (e.g. looking for a comma to split on). Is this the intended behavior?  Is there a better approach?

Comment: What about using ?sort=last%3Dasc - So the caller has to encode the equals sign to %3D and then you can simply split by =

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution cause the possible presence of multiple `sort` parameters inside your query string is avoid `String[]` and adopt the [`MultiValueMap`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) like below:

```java
public void getMultiValueMap(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> sort){}
```

You can use [`Pattern::splitAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) method to obtain a `Set` of strings as your expected result like below:

```java
public void getMultiValueMap(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> sort) {
        
    List<String> list = sort.get("sort");
    //add the string "id,desc" in case the sort parameter is empty ,list contains
    //only the "" string
    if (list.contains("")) {
       list.remove("");
       list.add("id,desc");
    }
    Set<String> set = list.stream()
                          .flatMap(Pattern.compile(",")::splitAsStream)
                          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}
```